# Maven task Failure in Azure Self hosted agent

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Running this on  Self-hosted windows machine.

```
 steps:
              - task: CmdLine@2
                inputs:
                  script: |
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JAVA_HOME]C:\Program Files (x86)\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_333"
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]C:\Program Files (x86)\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_333\bin;$(PATH)"
              - task: CmdLine@2
                inputs:
                  script: |
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=M2_HOME]C:\mvn"
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MAVEN_HOME]C:\mvn"
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]C:\mvn\bin;$(PATH)"
              - task: CmdLine@2
                inputs:
                  script: |
                    echo $(M2_HOME)
                    echo $(MAVEN_HOME)
                    echo $(PATH)
              - task: Cache@2
                inputs:
                  key: 'maven | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/pom.xml'
                  restoreKeys: |
                    maven | "$(Agent.OS)"
                    maven
                  path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
              - task: Maven@3
                inputs:
                  mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
                  mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m $(MAVEN_OPTS)'
                  goals: 'clean install'
                  publishJUnitResults: false
                  testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                  javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
                  mavenPath: 'c:\mvn'
                  mavenVersionOption: 'Path'
                  mavenSetM2Home: true
                  mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
                  effectivePomSkip: false
                  sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

The result of echo statements :

```
C:\mvn"
C:\mvn"
C:\mvn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\JAVA\jdk1.8.0_333\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps"
```

Question 1: Why there is double quotes at the end?

Question 2: My maven build has failed with the below reasons,

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "c:\mvn\bin\mvn.cmd -version" 
The syntax of the command is incorrect. Maven is not installed on the agent
##[error]Build failed.
```

Can some one help me identify what is the issue? Also do I need to mavenPath in the Maven task?

Could this be a problem because of JAVA_HOME?

Comment: you are setting ADO build variables with this `##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH]` - dont you actually want to set ENV vars on the build agent?

Comment: @silent When you say ENV variable, do you mean setting up the PATH, JAVA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME etc in the Agent Host just like we would on a Local machine?

Comment: yes, I assumed that is what you wanted to do?! btw, did you install java etc on your build agent?

Comment: Yes, Java is installed on the Machine, I thought we could set these variable in run time.

Comment: well of course you can, but not the way you are doing. just use a CMD task and export ENV vars like you would do when running locally in your CMD